cannot import name 'Service' from 'services' when using semantic-kernel
I am currently working through Microsoft's semantic-kernel exercises found here
But am getting the following error when I try to access the Services within the library.
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from services import Service
      3 # Select a service to use for this notebook (available services: OpenAI, AzureOpenAI, HuggingFace)
      4 selectedService = Service.OpenAI

ImportError: cannot import name 'Service' from 'services' (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\services\__init__.py)

Has anyone else had a similar issue? It seems the services library on pypi is something much older and not the one being used here by Microsoft.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

I have added the traceback to the question. Thank you.

I can't find any infrmation about module services. Maybe it exists only on Azure Servers and you have to run code on Azure. You have to ask author of this example and repo

It looks like it runs some module services which you have installed
but there is file services.py below 02-running-prompts-from-file.ipynb
https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/blob/main/python/notebooks/services.py
which you need to copy to folder with your code.

Frankly, services.py has only few lines which you could even put directly in your code
from enum import Enum


class Service(Enum):
    """
    Attributes:
        OpenAI (str): Represents the OpenAI service.
        AzureOpenAI (str): Represents the Azure OpenAI service.
        HuggingFace (str): Represents the HuggingFace service.
    """

    OpenAI = "openai"
    AzureOpenAI = "azureopenai"
    HuggingFace = "huggingface"

Or maybe you could even use
selectedService = "openai"

without using file services.py

Damn! I missed that file. Apologies if I have wasted your time, but thanks none the less!

Frankly, I missed that file too :) I spent some time checking other folders - searching services.py or requirements.txt. I also checked some documentation on Azure. Finally I started checking other notebooks (starting at 00-getting-started.ipynb) looking for configuration information. And then I saw services.py at the end of list :)
